# Changing column type from MEDIUMTEXT to JSON causes Cannot CAST value to JSON error on insert and update

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I'm using AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7. I have a column that is of type MEDIUMTEXT that I'd like to convert to JSON. After using an ALTER to accomplish this, I can neither update the newly JSON-typed field of an existing record nor insert new records. In both cases, a `Cannot CAST value to JSON` error is thrown. the default character set for this database is latin1, but the character set on this table is utf8.

The table is defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_sample` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `config` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

I've tried changing the column type via:

```
ALTER TABLE table_sample
    ADD COLUMN config2 JSON DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE table_sample
SET config2 = IF(JSON_VALID(config), config, NULL);

ALTER TABLE table_sample
    DROP COLUMN config;

ALTER TABLE table_sample
    CHANGE config2 config JSON;
```

Attempting to duplicate a record  like this, after the conversion to JSON, is one way to cause the aforementioned CAST error:

```
INSERT INTO table_sample (config)
SELECT config FROM table_sample WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: The obvious question is: what content is in the `config` column on the row with id=1?

Comment: @BillKarwin It's config data for PDF memo creation, so the values are a mix of numbers, strings, and HTML from tinyMCE. PHP and javascript's json decode functions don't have any trouble dealing with it, for what it's worth.

Comment: I think there must be some information you haven't included in your question. I tested the steps you show above. I tested both valid JSON content and also content that is not JSON. In neither case does it produce an error about CAST.

Comment: @BillKarwin This is a pretty old table, but I believe it was created in MySQL 5.6 with the character set of  latin1 and the config field was originally just TEXT. Before the database was upgraded to 5.7, the table had it's character set changed to utf8 and the config field was changed to MEDIUMTEXT.

Comment: *Attempting to duplicate a record like this, after the conversion to JSON, is one way to cause the aforementioned CAST error* Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53cd802ab1a0aabc8acee354b6a90da2 Edit the fiddle and show your issue.

Comment: I found a stored procedure to remove Smart Quotes and Dashes from the config field, and it was expecting and returning data of type mediumtext unicode; that looks like the real source of the issue. Sorry to waste your time!